# java.lang.IllegalStateException - Updated schema has 2 entity types, but incoming schema has 2

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I am using object box in my project. I am getting this crash in firebase console. This is full error:

```
       at io.objectbox.BoxStore.nativeCreateWithFlatOptions(BoxStore.java)
       at io.objectbox.BoxStore.<init>(BoxStore.java:268)
       at io.objectbox.BoxStoreBuilder.build(BoxStoreBuilder.java:549)
```

I have not changed anything in my code. This crash is coming all of a sudden
Anyone have any idea why this is coming? and any solution to this. I cannot find anything on net. Maybe this is issue is from object-box itself.

Comment: This seems to be https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/1156 Can you update to 3.7.1 and share any additional details, e.g. affected devices and operating system versions there? Thanks!